# cannot find package private (default) class in separate file in a different name in same package

Tags: java

I have a package called "test" and in that have a public class that contains the main method in a file called ABC.java.

```
package test;

public class ABC{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new T1();
    }
}
```

In that same package "test" I have two default classes T1 and T2 in a file called `T.java`

```
package test;

class T1 {}
class T2 {}
```

when i try to compile it it says cannot find symbol new `T1()`. When I put T1 in a separate file `T1.java` then it compiles fine. Why java is unable to find package private class in the same package.

Comment: Private as for the current Class, or file. Protected for package, Public for all

Comment: *Why java is unable to find package private class in the same package* In example they are default call not private!! and Yes private classes should be nested its another story

Comment: @Sarz :  Another name for *default* modifier is *package private*.  Top level classes cannot have `private`.

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Do you use IDE?

Comment: nope ... in the command line

Comment: Eclipse handles it without problems.

Comment: yes I have tried it. But i want to know why command line fails to do so

Comment: `javac` goes through `-sourcepath` looking for T1.java.  If it has to open every java file to see if the class is there, it would take too much time.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javac will automatically compile all the linked file used in the file you are compiling if there `.class` files are not found. Like in your case `ABC.java`. But one thing to notice is javac will not search for all the files with `.java` extension to be compiled. But it will look for the file name with the same name as the class. Like in your case `T1`.

So if you will compile `T.java` and then compile `ABC.java` it will run as expected. But if you compile `ABC.java` and not `T.java` compiler will not find `T1.class` then it will look for `T1.java`, but it will not found it too, which will give you an error. On the other hand if you will rename `T.java` to `T1.java` it will work as expected.

Comment: as in my question, I did not compile the T.java file separately I expect java to find it in the current package and compile it when I compile ABC.java, and it didn't found the class containing T1 class which is T.java. Why is not java unable to find it

Comment: @ron404 Sorry for misinterpreting your question. I have changed my post now.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`, When a class file name(*T1.java*) is same as class's name(*T1*) without `public` keyword, this class is public under this package(*test*)'s class.